# Реализация Pinch-to-zoom на Android

Tags: android

Каким способом в программе под Android можно реализовать технологию Pinch-to-zoom? К сожалению интерфейс OnGestureListener не предоставляет такой возможности

Answer (score 1):

Общая канва реализации такая:

1. Определяем `Gesture` (жест)
2. Ставим слушатель жеста `GestureDetector.onGestureListener`
3. В слушателе вычисляем расстояния и пропорционально им делаем зум

Более подробно [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375817/android-pinch-zoom)

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю к предыдущему ответу, что реализация самого зума делается с помощью классов Matrix и android.graphics.Camera, а GestureDetector для реализации привычных жестов. Кстати, также есть обработчики готовые для самого зуммирования, а задача сведется к добавлению функциональности для какого-либо класса от View.